# Strahler calculation ignoring large rivers

Tags: qgis, strahler

I have a DEM of a portion of the Yukon. I merged numerous DEM rasters then selected a subset for my AOI. I filled the sinks and then calculated the Strahler, but it seems to be ignoring large streams and rivers. The image shows Strahler >4 for reference.

[image]